# How to align equation items below their =

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

How is it possible to sort equations align with their = like this:

```
a*b*c = d*e*f
  g*h = i*j
    k = l*m*n
o*p*q = r
```

I've seen it before but I don't know how to find that!

Comment: I found something like want I seek in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43536/writing-steps-in-an-equation but not sure if it's the answer.

Comment: Are your asking for alignment of equations?  Standard latex has `eqnarray`, which is better replaced by the `align` from `amsmath`.

Comment: Take a look at Stefan Kottwitz's blog post at http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/, which compares different methods of aligning equations (in a nutshell: use `\begin{align}` with `\usepackage{amsmath}`)

Comment: The word `align` is the right word. The `amsmath` package provides the `align` environment (amongst others). Insert an ampersand `&` before every `=` and add ``\\`` after every line and you’re good to go. For more, check the [`amsmath` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) or the [tag:align] tag.

Comment: @AndrewSwann yes alignment was what I was looking for. thanks for mentioning eqnarry.@Jake Thanks man. The link was awesome. nothings better than a simple example which was on that site.@Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks you. you mentioned the pitfalls. very good.

Thanks all you guys I solved my problem with your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `align` environment which is provided by `amsmath`.

In the code below, an ampersand (&) denotes a vertical alignment point. Every line in the `align` environment will be aligned such that all ampersands are vertically aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    a*b*c &= d*e*f\\
    g*h &= i*j\\
    k &= l*m*n\\
    o*p*q &= r% \\ is not needed in this line!
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98397/enumerate-formulas/98401#98401

Answer (score 1):

If you need equation numbers, there are 2 options as follows.

### An equation number for each line

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}% change it back to
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% for my own purpose, remove this line!

\begin{align}
    a*b*c &= d*e*f\\
    g*h &= i*j\\
    k &= l*m*n\\
    o*p*q &= r% no \\ in this line!
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### An equation number for the whole as a group

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}% change it back to
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% for my own purpose, remove this line!

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    a*b*c &= d*e*f\\
    g*h &= i*j\\
    k &= l*m*n\\
    o*p*q &= r% no \\ in this line!
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you don't need equation numbers, replace `align` with `align*` or `equation` with `equation*`. `\[ ... \]` can also be used for the latter case!

Note: [`equation+split` versus `equation+aligned` can be found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109167/19356).

Comment: For the latter `equation` + `split` is better. `aligned` is for inline mode (not inline math-mode but inline alignment). See also [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128259/16595). And no, I have no [better source](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) to support that.

Comment: To handle the case of a single number for the entire set of equations for which only one alignment point is needed, I'd say you're better off using the `split` environment instead of the `aligned` environment.