# "!Missing $ inserted" error using amsmath environments

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I am trying to compile a document with equations but whenever I use `\begin{eqnarray}..\end{eqnarray}` or `\begin{align}...\end{align}` or anything like this I get the error msg `!Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$`. However if I type those equations without using `\begin{eqnarray}...\end{eqnarray}` or similar things I do not get any error msg and my document runs perfectly.

Even this simple thing does't work....Please help...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
$=$

\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `align` is automatically in math-mode. No need to enter it manually. Remove the `$`.

Comment: It is rather the dollar symbols that you should delete; the `align` environment already switches to math mode; the `$` are for inline math-mode.

Comment: Also, empty lines within `align` aren't allowed, I believe.

Comment: even after deleting the symbol its showing the same error...

Comment: its working now...thanx a lot..

Comment: all my equations are right indented.... how do i make them left indented???

Comment: Displayed equations are by default centered, if you want them pushed to the left, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54478/how-to-left-align-a-set-of-equations

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many of `amsmath` environments are already in math mode.

This applies to the environments

- `equation`,
- `align`,
- `gather`,
- `flalgin`,
- `alignat` and
- `multline`

as well as their starred (unnumbered) versions.

The environment `split` is to be used inside `amsmath` environments and can be used to split one equation on more than one line (this important for the equation number).

The environments

- `aligned`,
- `gathered` and
- `alignedat`

are similar to the version without `-ed` but are to be used in math mode.

As pointed out [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128243/errormissinginserted#comment288680_128243) by [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbjorn-t) empty lines aren’t allowed in math mode, they trigger the same error message.

---

`amsmath`’s environments (those who actually enter math mode) center their contents horizontally. The `align` family aligns its content internally at every odd `&`. See the example below how they work. You can use the `fleqn` option so that `amsmath` align the whole content of its environment at the left border (with a certain margin).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
            c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \\
a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = (a + b)^2
\end{gather}

\begin{align}
\text{right-aligned} & \neq \text{left-aligned} \nonumber\\
                 c^2 & = a^2 + b^2 \\
     a^2 + 2ab + b^2 & = (a + b)^2
\end{align}

\begin{align}
            c^2 & = a^2 + b^2 \\
\begin{split}
a^2 + 2ab + b^2 & = (a + b)^2 \\
                & = (a + b)(a + b) \\
                & = aa + ab + ba + bb \\
                & = a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]