# How to write this equation in publication?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have the equation in the twocolumn view

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}   

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}  
X(m) &= \frac{b-a}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} e^{-i2\pi (k-1)(m-1)/N} x(a + (b-a)\frac{k-1}{N}) \\ 
&= \frac{b-a}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} e^{-i2\pi (a + (b-a)\frac{k-1}{N})*\frac{m-1}{b-a}} \\
& x(a + (b-a)\frac{k-1}{N})e^{i2\pi a \frac{m-1}{b-a}} \\
& \xrightarrow{ N\to\infty } \int_{a}^{b} e^{-2\pi t \frac{m-1}{b-a}} x(t) dt\\
& e^{i2\pi a \frac{m-1}{b-a}} Qx(\frac{m-1}{b-a}). 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

**How would you present this equation in a twocolumn view?**

Comment: Please don't just include snippets but a minimal code that can be typeset, from `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}`, removing the unnecessary code.

Comment: You mean `aligned` and not `align`, don't you?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't like how it looks and you would want suggestions on how to have it look better?

Comment: Don't nest `align` and `equation` environments. Both enter math-mode on their own, see [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128243/16595).

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes. I have also thought to split in two. Now, it looks quite a messy.

Comment: So is the question that the top line is too long - what to do about it?  re Brackets, you can use `\left(` and `\right)` to automate the sizing nicely

Comment: Could you show the equation without splitting first to let me know where the exact place I have to break the equation?

Comment: It looks too wide to just tighten with some negative spaces (and will get wider with the right size brackets). I would say the best option is to have a [full-width equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/one-column-equation-in-twocolumn-document-class).

Comment: I splitted the other question about brackets here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139445/automatically-size-the-brackets-by-left-and-right to concentrate here only to the layout. @ChrisH

Comment: @Masi Use `a_{k}` instead of `a+(b-a)\frac{k-1}{N}`, to begin with.

Comment: @egreg I was going to suggest that. I will also add that there should be larger parentheses around `\frac{m-1}{b-a}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be using `split` not `align` inside `equation`.  Introducing new variables for large repeating expressions and shifting your indexing by one will reduce the size of the equation.  Finally I introduce an `eqbreak` command to shift a split expression:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}

\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}

\begin{document}   

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}  
    X(m+1)
    &= \frac{b-a}N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} e^{-i2\pi km/N}\,  x(a_k) \\
    &= \frac{b-a}N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} e^{-i2\pi a_km/(b-a)} \eqbreak[6]
    \times x(a_k)\,e^{i2\pi a m/(b-a)} \\
    &\xrightarrow{N\to\infty} e^{i2\pi a m/(b-a)} \,Qx\Bigl(\frac
    m{b-a}\Bigr),
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
where \( a_k = a + (b-a)k/N \).
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I just told to Marienplatz, I'm not sure that `\times` is the right symbol to use...

Comment: @karlkoeller An alternative would be `\cdot`, but it depends on the wider context.

Comment: @Marienplatz There is no integral in the poster's example, nor is `Qx` explained.

Comment: I would go with `\cdot`... Anyway, as a mathematician, I would say that this is the only answer that looks good, IMHO. +1.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Can you please give your feedback here about applying your `\eqbreak` in Tables http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324097/13173 I am just using `\aligned` at the moment and cannot understand possible complications of not using `\begin{equation}\begin{split}...\end{split}\end{equation}` there.

Comment: @Masi I will comment on that question - you are missing alignment points.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Here is more simpler thread just using your Math in Table: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324191/13173 You can also propose an answer there and/or comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}  
X(m) 
&=
\!
\begin{multlined}[t]
    \frac{b-a}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \Bigg[  x\left(a + \frac{k-1}{N}(b-a)\right)\\
    \times e^{-\frac{2\pi i (k-1)(m-1)}{N}} \Bigg]
\end{multlined}\\ 
&=
\!
\begin{multlined}[t]
    \frac{b-a}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N}\Bigg[ x\left(a + \frac{k-1}{N}(b-a)\right) \\
    \times e^{2\pi i a \frac{m-1}{b-a}}\\
    \times e^{-2\pi i \left(a + \frac{k-1}{N}(b-a)\right)\times \frac{m-1}{b-a}}\Bigg]
\end{multlined}\\
& \xrightarrow{ N\to\infty }
\!
\begin{multlined}[t] 
    e^{2\pi i a \frac{m-1}{b-a}} \\
    \times \int_{a}^{b} e^{2\pi i a \frac{m-1}{b-a}} Qx\left(\frac{m-1}{b-a}\right).
\end{multlined}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that `\times` is the right symbol to use...

Answer (score 3):

I would propose you split the first two lines at a reasonably natural point. I would use explicit sizing instructions for the parentheses, and use `\exp(...)` expressions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&X(m) \notag\\
&= \frac{b-a}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \exp\bigl(-i2\pi (k-1)(m-1)/N\bigr) \notag\\
&\qquad  \times x\Bigl[a + (b-a)\frac{k-1}{N}\Bigr] \\
&= \frac{b-a}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \exp\Bigl[-i2\pi \Bigl(a + (b-a)\frac{k-1}{N}\Bigr)
 \frac{m-1}{b-a}\Bigr] \notag \\
&\qquad  \times x\Bigl(a + (b-a)\frac{k-1}{N}\Bigr) 
        \exp\Bigl(i2\pi a \frac{m-1}{b-a}\Bigr) \\
& \xrightarrow{ N\to\infty } \exp\Bigl(i2\pi a \frac{m-1}{b-a}\Bigr) 
Qx\Bigl(\frac{m-1}{b-a}\Bigr)\,.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```