# Math in a table

Tags: tables, amsmath

Im trying to put some `\times` and `\power` in a table, but it isn't quite working.

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{tabular}{| p{3cm} | p{9cm} }
\hline
\bf hardware & \bf rekensom\\
\hline
6506E & 1 - (1 - 0.9999909)^2 = 0.99999999991 * 100% = 99.9999999917%\\
\hline
6509E & 1 - (1 - 0.9999885)^2 = 0.99999999986 * 100% = 99.9999999868%\\
\hline
\end {tabular}
```

I also tried this, but it didnt work either:

```
\hline
6506E &  $$ 1 - (1 - 0.9999909)\power2 = 0.99999999991 \times 100\% $$\\
\hline
```

The error it gives here is

> Undefined control sequence

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Go with only one `$`.

Comment: I tried to use 1 $, that also didnt help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Great tip, I didnt even thought about that ! I will do so the next time :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. Please avoid `\bf` in favor of `\textbf{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| p{3cm} | p{9cm} }
\hline
\textbf{hardware} & \textbf{rekensom} \\
\hline
6506E & $1 - (1 - 0.9999909)^2 = 0.99999999991 * 100\% = 99.9999999917\%$ \\
\hline
6509E & $1 - (1 - 0.9999885)^2 = 0.99999999986 * 100\% = 99.9999999868\%$ \\
\hline
\end {tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

Here, have a slightly enhanced version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{0.7\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    Hardware & Rekensom \cr
    \midrule
    6506E &
    $\aligned
        1 - (1 - 0.9999909)^2 &= 0.99999999991 \cdot 100\,\% \\
        &= 99.9999999917\,\%
    \endaligned$ \cr
    6509E &
    $\aligned
        1 - (1 - 0.9999885)^2 &= 0.99999999986 \cdot 100\,\% \\
        &= 99.9999999868\,\%
    \endaligned$ \cr
    \bottomrule
\end {tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider your title's topic with a little more challenging input with integrals. 
I find Andrew's `\eqbreak` in `\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}` in table as a more configurable option here. 
Your table goes well with Henri's example but if you get integrals and other challenging operators `eqbreak` is useful. 
Changes

- no `booktabs` with vertical lines [Zarko]
- Andrew's `\eqbreak` for challenging operators etc integrals
- `\bgroup\def\arraystretch{1.5} ... \egroup` for more space in cells
- Explicitly `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}` [Andrew2]

Your example with integrals

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,rotating}
\usepackage{physics}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139450/13173
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324197/13173
\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\begin{tabular}{| l | p{0.7\linewidth} |}
    \hline
    Hardware & Rekensom \\ \hline
    6506E &
    $\begin{aligned}
        1 - (1 - 0.9999909)^2 \eqbreak[-2] \times \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} A x \cdot \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} B y \times Z \alpha \, \text{dy} \, \text{dx} \\ &= 0.99999999991 \cdot 100\,\% \\
        &= 99.9999999917\,\%
    \end{aligned}$ \\ \hline
    6509E &
    $\begin{aligned}
        1 - (1 - 0.9999885)^2 &= 0.99999999986 \cdot 100\,\% \\
        &= 99.9999999868\,\%
    \end{aligned}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Limitations

- no known

Comment: nice solution (+1), however, never mix `booktabs` rules with vertical lines: result is ugly.  Also instead your interesting macro might to be better to use `multline` environment from `asmamth/mathtool` package (just my opinion).

Comment: @Zarko Please, feel free to show us how you can do the thing with `multiline` and `amsmath/mathtool`.