# How to fit large sideways table with Equations/References on A4?

Tags: tables, equations

I have a big Table with long equations and references in some of the entries which overflow the margin. I want to decrease the column width in the table and fit the table better on the page. I decrease font size to decrease complications but it is not sustainable. 
Pseudocode

1. Normal size font.
2. Have more vertical space in the table.
3. Decrease the column width.
4. More rows per cell entry.
5. Extra spacing.

Fig. 1 .tex file, Fig. 2 The big table with long equations looks where I would like the table to take more vertical space and fit the page better, Fig. 3 Output of Masi's first code and my edit for long equations, Fig. 4  Output of Zarko's first code and my edit for long equations.

[image]
[image]
[image]

*MWE1 with easier-to-manage cases*

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{Ideals computed with basis and lexicographic}
\label{GroebnerRHR}
\hspace*{-2cm}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l |}
    \hline
    CountVars & Description                 &   Basis           &   Count of elements   &   Count of Monomials      \\
    \hline
    1       &   system 1                    &   0           &   0               &   0           \\
    2       &   system 2                    &   0       &   0               &   0           \\
    2       &   system 3                    &   1       &   1               &   2           \\
    3       &   series system with 3 vertices   &   1+3     &   1               &   6           \\
    5       &   See Figure 15.              &   medium size equation            &   0               &   0           \\
    7       &   See Figure 28.              &   $long equation+ long long- long long long long- long* long long= long equation$         &   9               &   20          \\  
    36      &   PP                      &   $very long =equation 1+2 stereo aloe nag rouen haosteu +saohu natoehs untaose thaoetu saothe staehosun haotnh saonthe + snatohu snthaosun thaosnth oanteuh+ snoathu sntoahe - snthoasen thoastn hosatnh soah sntohaent hoasnu hsonatheu * toha snahous$     &   899             &   2222    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

*MWE2 by Masi*

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{Ideals computed with basis and lexicographic}
\label{GroebnerRHR}
\hspace*{-2cm}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31681/13173
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\begin{tabular}{| l | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |}
    \hline
    CountVars & Description                       &   Basis   &   Count of elements   &   Count of Monomials      \\ \hline
    1         &   system 1                        &   0       &   0                   &   0           \\ \hline
    2         &   system 2                        &   0       &   0                   &   0           \\ \hline
    2         &   system 3                        &   1       &   1                   &   2           \\ \hline
    3         &   series system with 3 vertices   &   1+3     &   1                   &   6           \\ \hline
    5         &   See Figure 15.                  &   medium size equation            &   0               &   0           \\ \hline
    7         &   See Figure 28.                  &   $long equation = long long +long long- long long *long long *long+long$         &   9               &   20          \\ \hline
    36        &   PP                              &   $very long equation = stereo- aloe+nag - rouen *haosteu saohu natoehs -untaose thaoetu +saothe staehosun haotnh saonthe snatohu +snthaosun thaosnth oanteuh snoathu sntoahe +snthoasen thoastn hosatnh soah sntohaent hoasnu hsonatheu -toha snahous$      &   899             &   2222    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

where the equations entries do not get nicely presented in the columns but go over other columns, how to fix this by making the equations to continue on the next line?

*MWE3 with Zarko*

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,rotating}
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\caption{Ideals computed with basis and lexicographic}
    \label{GroebnerRHR}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| r |p{8em} | X | l | l |}
    \hline
\thead[b]{Count\\Vars} 
        &   \thead[b]{Description}
            &   \thead[b]{Basis}   
                &   \thead[b]{Count of\\ elements} 
                    &   \thead[b]{Count of\\ Monomials}    \\ \hline
1       &   system 1                        
            & 0 & 0 & 0                                 \\ \hline
2       &   system 2                        
            & 0 & 0 & 0                                 \\ \hline
2       &   system 3                        
            & 1 & 1 & 2                                 \\ \hline 
3       &   series system with 3 vertices   
            & 1+3   & 1 & 6                             \\ \hline
5       &   See Figure 15.                  
            &   medium size equation            
                & 0 & 0                                 \\ \hline
7       &   See Figure 28.                  
            &   $long equation = if *it is longer +than is column width - then it hed to be set * as multi line equation + with help of `asmmath` or `mathtool` math environments$
                & 9  & 20                               \\ \hline
36      &   PP                              
            &   $very long equation = stereo +aloe nag rouen haosteu - saohu natoehs untaose thaoetu +saothe staehosun haotnh saonthe snatohu - snthaosun thaosnth -oanteuh snoathu sntoahe snthoasen thoastn hosatnh soah sntohaent +hoasnu hsonatheu toha snahous$   
                & 899   & 2222                          \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, do you want to increase the text area (geometry, \newgeometry), shrink the table (graphicx \resizebox), or increase the paper size (pgfpages, \pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper})?

Comment: @Masi I added MWE2 where linebreaks not in equations.

Comment: Your examples are not really examples as tex allows linebreaking in math at specific points at binary operators and relations but `$very stereo aloe nag rouen haosteu saohu natoehs un` has no break points. Is your real example a math expression with no break points? if so it will not break (sideways table doesn't seem related)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the equations do have binary operations such as +-*, I added them to MWEs

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to sidewaystables, or math you just have very lumpy copy in a narrow text width so you should set it raggedright not try to justify it. Changing `X` to `{\raggedright}X` in for example MW3 makes it all fit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you please expand your comment as an answer. Please, add some break points to your example too.

Answer (score 2):

Fig. 1 Output without long equations, Fig. 2 Output with long equations

[image]
[image]

### Codes

Code 1 without long equations

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{Ideals computed with basis and lexicographic}
\label{GroebnerRHR}
\hspace*{-2cm}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31681/13173
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\begin{tabular}{| l | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |}
    \hline
    CountVars & Description                       &   Basis   &   Count of elements   &   Count of Monomials      \\ \hline
    1         &   system 1                        &   0       &   0                   &   0           \\ \hline
    2         &   system 2                        &   0       &   0                   &   0           \\ \hline
    2         &   system 3                        &   1       &   1                   &   2           \\ \hline
    3         &   series system with 3 vertices   &   1+3     &   1                   &   6           \\ \hline
    5         &   See Figure 15.                  &   medium size equation            &   0               &   0           \\ \hline
    7         &   See Figure 28.                  &   long equation long long long long long long long long long long         &   9               &   20          \\ \hline
    36        &   PP                              &   very stereo aloe nag rouen haosteu saohu natoehs untaose thaoetu saothe staehosun haotnh saonthe snatohu snthaosun thaosnth oanteuh snoathu sntoahe snthoasen thoastn hosatnh soah sntohaent hoasnu hsonatheu toha snahous      &   899             &   2222    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Code 2 with long equations and with Andrew's fix [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324197/13173) about the environment

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,rotating}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139450/13173
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324197/13173
\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{Ideals computed with basis and lexicographic}
\label{GroebnerRHR}
\hspace*{-2cm}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31681/13173
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\renewcommand{\eqbreak}[1][1]{\\&\hskip#1em} % to save horizontal space as requested by OP so from 2 to 1; arraystretch just affects vertical spacing so it has nothing to do here
\begin{tabular}{| l | p{3cm} | p{5cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} |}
    \hline
    CountVars & Description                       &   Basis   &   Count of elements   &   Count of Monomials      \\ \hline
    1         &   system 1                        &   0       &   0                   &   0           \\ \hline
    2         &   system 2                        &   0       &   0                   &   0           \\ \hline
    2         &   system 3                        &   1       &   1                   &   2           \\ \hline
    3         &   series system with 3 vertices   &   1+3     &   1                   &   6           \\ \hline
    5         &   See Figure 15.                  &   medium size equation            &   0               &   0           \\ \hline
    7         &   See Figure 28.                  &
                                                $\begin{aligned}
                                                   long equation long long 
                                                     \eqbreak[-5] \times long long long \\ 
                                                   =long long long long long         
                                                \end{aligned}$
                                                  &   9       &   20          \\ \hline
    36        &   PP                              &
                                                $\begin{aligned}
                                                        very stereo aloe nag rouen 
                                                        \eqbreak[-11] \times haosteu saohu natoehs \eqbreak[-11] \times untaose thaoetu staehosun \eqbreak[-11] \times saonthe snthaosun thaosnth \eqbreak[-11] \times oanteuh snoathu sntoahe \eqbreak[-11] \times thoastn hosatnh soah sntohaent \eqbreak[-11] \times hoasnu hsonatheu toha snahous \end{aligned}$                           
                                                  &   81111   &   2222    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Optional remarks

- Better example with more challenging Math symbols etc integrals [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324191/13173) about *Math in a table*
- You can likely remove `\hspace*{-2cm}` because negative spacing may not be needed anymore, at least, I think the third column looks funny in Fig. 1. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89090/13173) about general `\hspace` spacing

Comment: See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oaTSn.png) where the column entries are equations not text: the equations go over other columns, how to fix this? (updated to the Q with slightly modified version of your MWE)

Answer (score 1):

See, if the following  reformatting gives what you like to achieve:

[image]

In creating this table looks-out I use two packages: `makecell` from which I use (default set) macro `thead` for setting column heads in two lines, and `tabularx` package to spread table over whole text width in `sidewaystable` (which equal to text height in normal pages) and use cell for multi row equation if itis necessary. Also I assume, that you wish to have maximal possible width in third column where is long equation, and that multi line text is expected in the second (more narrow) column.

As is noted in MWE below, if long equation can not be fit in avilable column width, I suggest to use one of among `amsmath` or `mathtool` math environments, preferable `multilined` from `mathtools` (to bi more indicative, I need more information about your equation).

Package `geometry` with option `showframe` I used to show page layout and also define more usual its size.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,rotating}
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\caption{Ideals computed with basis and lexicographic}
    \label{GroebnerRHR}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| r |p{8em} | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X | l | l |}
    \hline
\thead[b]{Count\\Vars} 
        &   \thead[b]{Description}
            &   \thead[b]{Basis}   
                &   \thead[b]{Count of\\ elements} 
                    &   \thead[b]{Count of\\ Monomials}    \\ \hline
1       &   system 1                        
            & 0 & 0 & 0                                 \\ \hline
2       &   system 2                        
            & 0 & 0 & 0                                 \\ \hline
2       &   system 3                        
            & 1 & 1 & 2                                 \\ \hline 
3       &   series system with 3 vertices   
            & 1+3   & 1 & 6                             \\ \hline
5       &   See Figure 15.                  
            &   medium size equation            
                & 0 & 0                                 \\ \hline
7       &   See Figure 28.                  
            &   long equation, if it is longer than is column width then it hed to be set as multi line equation with help of `asmmath` or `mathtool` math environments
                & 9  & 20                               \\ \hline
% alternatively for above row (added as described in addendum)
7       &   See Figure 28.
            &   $
                 a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3^3 + a_4x^4 + a_5x^5 + a_6x^6 + a_7x^7 + a_8x^8 + a_9x^9 + a_{10} + a_{11}x^{11} + a_{12}x^{12} + a^{13}x{13} + a^{14}x^{14} + a_{15}x^{15} + a_{16}x^{16} + a_{17}x^{17} + a_{18}x^{18} + a_{19}x^{19} + a_{20}x^{20} + a_{21}x^{21}
                $
                & 9  & 20                               \\ \hline
%
36      &   PP                              
            &   very stereo aloe nag rouen haosteu saohu natoehs untaose thaoetu saothe staehosun haotnh saonthe snatohu snthaosun thaosnth oanteuh snoathu sntoahe snthoasen thoastn hosatnh soah sntohaent hoasnu hsonatheu toha snahous      
                & 899   & 2222                          \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Till to now I newer seen variable set `$long equation, if it is longer than is column width then it had to be set as multi line equation with help of`asmmath`or`mathtools`math environments$`! This "text" math consider as one long sequence of variables. See your result, all characters are tied together and between them is no space for braking equation. In normal circumstances row with long equation probably is something like this:

```
7       &   See Figure 28.
            &   $
                 a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3^3 + a_4x^4 + a_5x^5 + a_6x^6 + a_7x^7 + a_8x^8 + a_9x^9 + a_{10} + a_{11}x^{11} + a_{12}x^{12} + a^{13}x{13} + a^{14}x^{14} + a_{15}x^{15} + a_{16}x^{16} + a_{17}x^{17} + a_{18}x^{18} + a_{19}x^{19} + a_{20}x^{20} + a_{21}x^{21}
                $
                & 9  & 20                               \\ \hline
```

I consider above row in my MWE and also include to answer the new image of table. Since you still didn't give any indication what is your really equation, I didn't use any other math environment which enable to structure equation on some other way (with manual tweaking of breaking points).

**Edit:** 
For better align contents in cells of the third column -- as suggest David Carlisle in his comment below -- seems to be sensible change column type `X` to

```
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
```

or maybe to

```
>{\RraggedRight\arraybackslash}X
```

which require to load package `ragged2e` in document preamble. I improve my first suggestion with above expalined and accordingly replace image of the obtained table.

Comment: I added MWE3 with long equation enviroment [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qiNlj.png) slightly changing your alternative with long equation environment and I get the same problem as with Masi's alternative -- the column entries of long equations go over other columns. How to fix that?

Comment: I pointed this in text where I suspect you like to have long equation :-). You write equation on wrog way. See addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Zarko if you change `X` to `>{\raggedright}X` I suspect this answer would be accepted (see comments under the question:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you suggestion. I will consider it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code 2 example you are missing alignment points in the `aligned` expressions.  If you don't put a `&` on the first line of an `aligned` it is implicitly at the right-hand end.  So you should be writing something like

```
$\begin{aligned}
  &long equation long long
  \eqbreak
  \times long long long \\
  &=long long long long long
\end{aligned}$
```

Putting this in to a basic example of your table gives

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsfonts,rotating}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139450/13173
\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \caption{Ideals computed with basis and lexicographic}
  \label{GroebnerRHR}
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31681/13173
  \def\arraystretch{1.5}% 1 is the default, change whatever you need
  \renewcommand{\eqbreak}[1][1]{\\&\hskip#1em}
  \begin{tabular}{ p{3cm} p{6cm} p{2cm}}
    \toprule
    Description & Basis &   Count of elements \\ \midrule
    See Figure 28. & $\begin{aligned}
      &long equation long long
      \eqbreak
      \times long long long \\
      &=long long long long long
    \end{aligned}$ & 9 \\ \midrule
    PP & $\begin{aligned}
      &very stereo aloe nag rouen \eqbreak
      \times haosteu saohu natoehs \eqbreak
      \times untaose thaoetu staehosun \eqbreak
      \times saonthe snthaosun thaosnth \eqbreak
      \times oanteuh snoathu sntoahe \eqbreak
      \times thoastn hosatnh soah sntohaent \eqbreak
      \times hoasnu hsonatheu toha snahous
    \end{aligned}$ & 81111 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

I have renewed the `\eqbreak` command for this table, so its default indent is `1em` instead of `2em`.

Comment: You define two times `eqbreak` with just one small difference (`[1][2]` vs `[1][1]`) . Is there reason for that? It seems it has to be done because there is the command `\def\arraystretch{1.5}`. Right? - - I cannot see any changes in the output by the re-definition.

Comment: @Masi I only did because the poster wants to save horizontal space, so I redefined the default argument from `2` to `1`.  It has nothing to do with the `\arraystretch` which affects vertical spacing.