# Writing two right hand sides in an equation in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to write LATeX code whose output should look like this:

```
A = B + C
  = 2 + 3
```

I'm trying to write the following code in LATeX:

```
\begin{equation}
A &= B + C \\
  &= 2 + 3
```

But the output of this code is:

```
A = B + C = 2 + 3
```

How to change the latex code to achieve the required output?

Comment: use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package

Comment: And don't forget `\end{align}` (or whatever you use).

Comment: For more, see the [tag:align] tag and [How to align equation items below their `=`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126811)

Comment: for unnumbered equations use the stared version `align*`.

Answer (score 2):

## Remarks

For detailed information on the `mathmode` and other neat tricks with mathematics in LaTeX, consult [the `amsmath` guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) and Herbert Voß' excellent [`mathmode` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf).

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% remove page number for cropping
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    A &= B + C \\
      &= 2 + 3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Possibly `equation` with `split` if a number is wanted

Comment: @egreg Of course you are right, but there are tons of ways to write a multiline equation, so that I just pointed out one way and linked the documentation. If I was missing any important things, feel free to add them.